# Project structure with Python error

Tags: python

I have a question about project structure. I have all file in main project package. I would like to create three packages and separated files.

When I do it, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "file.py", line 5, in <module> 
from script.login import LoginTest 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script'
```

I checked, it can be about the interpreter. I have corrected it according to the guidelines and continue to do the same.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 5, in <module>
    from script.login import LoginTest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script'

Comment: Could you please show your project structure: dirs, files?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your `main.py` in your top most folder. If you want to use a module from an other packge you have to import it. If your subfolder is named `package1` and your script inside this folder is named `script.py` you can import that script and use a function from there with:

```
from package1 import script

# Call a function in script.py like that
script.func()
```

Comment: I remove tag :), I make this agree with your suggest, but my problem don't disappear

Comment: @Tom1416 This suggestion will work only if you place `__init__.py` in package1 dir. So I repeat, please show us you dirs, files structure.